# How create dict inside dict by string using dot

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict list of dicts.

```
dict_list = [
    {"nameClient": "client.name"},
    {"emailClient": "client.email"},
    {"Document.typeDocument": "client.type_document"},
    {"Document.numberDocument": "client.number_document"},
    {"Document.docOne.number": "client.docone_number"},
    {"Document.docOne.type": "client.docone_type"},
    {"Document.docTwo.number": "client.doctwo_number"},
    {"Document.docOne.extra.number": "client.docone_extra_number"},
]
```

I want to create a dict based on key of this dicts and get value from my class based on value of this dicts.

Client Class and Values initialized:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.name = data['name']
        self.email = data['email']
        self.type_document = data['type_document']
        self.number_document = data['number_document']
        self.docone_number = data['docone_number']
        self.docone_type = data['docone_type']
        self.doctwo_number = data['doctwo_number']
        self.docone_extra_number = data['docone_extra_number']
        
# this will be passed on build_final_dict(FINAL_DICT, i, k, v, client)
client1 = Client({
    "name": "Stack",
    "email": "xxxxx@xxxx.com",
    "type_document": "TPS",
    "number_document": "22222222",
    "docone_number": "11111111",
    "docone_type": "docone type",
    "doctwo_number": "doc two number",
    "docone_extra_number": "doc extra number",
})
```

**So I started passing to a function the key/value**

```
FINAL_DICT = {}

for i in dict_list:
    for k, v in i.items():
        build_final_dict(FINAL_DICT, i, k, v, client)
```

My **build_final_dict()**

```
def build_final_dict(FINAL_DICT, i, k, v, client):
    if '.' not in k:
        FINAL_DICT[k] = getattr(client, v.replace('client.', ''))
    else:
        subdict = k.split('.')[0] # ex documento
        subdict_key = i.items()[0][0]
        subdict_key = subdict_key.replace('%s.' % subdict, '')
        subdict_value = i.items()[0][1]
        subdict_value = subdict_value.replace('client.', '')
        
        if subdict not in FINAL_DICT:
            FINAL_DICT[subdict] = dict()
        
        result_value = getattr(client, subdict_value)
        
        if '.' not in subdict_key:
            FINAL_DICT[subdict][subdict_key] = result_value
        else:
            new_subkey = subdict_key.split('.')[0]
            new_subvalue = subdict_key.split('.')[1]
            if new_subkey not in FINAL_DICT[subdict]:
                FINAL_DICT[subdict][new_subkey] = dict()
            build_final_dict(FINAL_DICT[subdict][new_subkey], i, new_subvalue, v, client)
```

**Actual Result:**

```
{
   "emailClient":"xxxxx@xxxx.com",
   "nameClient":"Stack",
   "Document":{
      "typeDocument":"TPS",
      "numberDocument":"22222222",
      "docTwo":{
         "number":"doc two number"
      },
      "docOne":{
         "type":"docone type",
         "extra":"doc extra number", // should continue creating dict within dict...
         "number":"11111111"
      }
   }
}
```

Most of the dictionary is right. But the "extra" dictionary that I put inside a dictionary (third sub level) did not create a new dictionary and put the final value.

There is the possibility of having infinite sub dictionaries, I need my script to be prepared for that.

**Result I expected (based on Client class Data):**

```
{
   "emailClient":"xxxxx@xxxx.com",
   "nameClient":"Stack",
   "Document":{
      "typeDocument":"TPS",
      "numberDocument":"22222222",
      "docTwo":{
         "number":"doc two number"
      },
      "docOne":{
         "type":"docone type",
         "extra": { "number": "doc extra number" }, // dict, not string
         "number":"11111111"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample input to the outputs you've mentioned? Also an example of when infinite sub-dicts would be warranted.

Comment: the first code is the dictionary list example. Each dot in the "key" would be a new dictionary. The "client" is a class that already has the data. This part is ok, the problem is in generating the dictionaries from the sub dictionary. There can be infinitely many sub dictionaries, for example: "dict1.dict2.dict3.dict4.attribute". I need to create the dictionaries based on this. I put all the example code in the question. Thanks! @RoboMop

Comment: The outputs you gave have values that clearly aren't in the inputs. What is "xxxx"? If we don't know what the data is, we obviously won't be able to provide a solution for it.

Comment: I added the client class and initial values. @RoboMop

Comment: Could you share the structure of your class, it's hard to make out the attributes from the code.

Comment: @SayandipDutta I added the class in question, check the second code, thank you!

Comment: I changed values from result to be equals the class. sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this will help you in transforming the initial JSON to the structure you need. This is in accordance to your original requirement of

> I want to create a dict based on key of this dicts and get value from
> my class based on value of this dicts.

I would try this in a split approach, to create nested dicts for every dict in your list (if they have nesting in keys), and then merge them together as single unit.
See an example approach here:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from functools import reduce


def merge(d1, d2):
    # Merge 2 dictionaries -deep.
    for k, v in d1.items():
        if k in d2:
            if all(isinstance(e, MutableMapping) for e in (v, d2[k])):
                d2[k] = merge(v, d2[k])
    md = d1.copy()
    md.update(d2)
    return md


def explode_to_dict(key, value):
    # Create nested dicts based on the key structure
    if "." in key:
        p, c = key.rsplit(".", 1)
        return explode_to_dict(p, {c: value})
    else:
        return {key: value}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_list = [
        {"nameClient": "client.name"},
        {"emailClient": "client.email"},
        {"Document.typeDocument": "client.type_document"},
        {"Document.numberDocument": "client.number_document"},
        {"Document.docOne.number": "client.docone_number"},
        {"Document.docOne.type": "client.docone_type"},
        {"Document.docTwo.number": "client.doctwo_number"},
        {"Document.docOne.extra.number": "client.docone_extra_number"},
    ]
    result_dict = {}
    result_dict = reduce(merge, [explode_to_dict(*d.popitem()) for d in dict_list])
    print(json.dumps(result_dict))
```

This provides a structure like below(expected):

```
{
    "nameClient": "client.name",
    "emailClient": "client.email",
    "Document": {
        "typeDocument": "client.type_document",
        "numberDocument": "client.number_document",
        "docOne": {
            "number": "client.docone_number",
            "type": "client.docone_type",
            "extra": {
                "number": "client.docone_extra_number"
            }
        },
        "docTwo": {
            "number": "client.doctwo_number"
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose, you can proceed with your class manipulation from here!

Comment: You saved my life. Worked perfectly. I just needed to change the dictionary value to the attribute value in the class and it worked. I did tests with more subdicts and it also worked. Thanks!